# Cant send bulk messages to socket swing GUI Freezing

Tags: java, swing, sockets, tcp, while-loop

I am new to java programming and trying to develop a java application which reads bulk messages from log files and stores messages in arraylist. now I am trying to send multiple messages which are stored in arraylist to tcp socket but my GUI is freezing in while loop.

Below is the code so far

```
public static void SendRequest( ArrayList<String> rawMessages) {
    int ind = 0;
        do  {
            logs_res = "";
            logs_req = "";
            Socket socket = new Socket(IP, port);
            socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
            String line = "";
            System.out.println("Request  : " + rawMessages.get(ind);
            out.writeUTF(rawMessages.get(ind);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            out.flush();
            try {                   
                if (ind == rawMessages.size()) {
                    socket.close();
                } else {
                    ind++;
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Request  : " + line);                       
                    sin.close();
                    sout.close();
                    in.close();
                    out.close();

                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {


                System.out.println("E1" + e);
            } 
        }while(abc.size() == ind);
```

}

Comment: You need to read about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). All time consuming operations must be performed outside of the main Swing thread (aka. Event Dispatcher Thread or EDT).

Comment: And you're doing a sleep(500) and expecting there to be no freezing?

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("E1" + e);` would shorter (and better,) be `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();` General tips: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: .. 3) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. Please [edit] the question to add 4 space chars ahead of the closing `}` at the end of the code. 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: I fixed the problem by using threading. Thank you @SergiyMedvynskyy for giving correct direction.